# Export object to excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

What is the best way to export objet to excel file in C# (.net framework 3.5)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of object?  Is it a collection of things or whatnot?

Comment: It's a complicated object (conatins amongst other, lists etc'), but what i have to do is to process the data in the object and export it to excel sheet. can you help?

Comment: what format of Excel file?  xls? xlsx? csv? or anything as long as Excel can open it?  And if the latter, which version(s) of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

If it's tabular data, you could generate HTML tables and let Excel open it up intuitively.  Otherwise I'd recommend COM Interop.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate xlsx files (basically reports - SQL Reporting Services 2008 R2 still doesn't support it natively, just the older xls).

I've heard good things about [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), which is a .NET port of the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org/)

If you want to do it 'natively' and interop with a real instance of Excel, you can use the classes in Excel's Primary Interop Assembly - look in the [microsoft.office.interop.excel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx)

A lot depends on what kind of objects you have already and what you want your intended output to be - if you can specify more of that, we can give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used the clipboard to save objects to multiple formats that can then be pasted into different applications including Excel or Word, tyring to find an example online I stumble across this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023

Looks Good!